Number of ways to draw $3$ cards from $26$ cards, numbered $1-26$, so that the difference between any of the two cards drawn is at least $2$

A box contains $26$ cards, numbered from $1$ to $26$. Draw $3$ cards at random from the box. How many ways to do this so that any two of the cards drawn have numbers whose difference is at least $2$?

I'm aware that I've been asking too many probability questions recently but the material I just found doesn't come with an answer key so I can only rely on others on this site for problems I'm not 100% sure I've got the correct answer. I hope everyone doesn't mind.
My solution:
Let $x, y, z$ ($x < y < z$) be the numbers written on the three cards drawn. Since any of the cards have numbers whose difference is at least 2, we have:
$x \geq 1$
$y \geq x + 2$
$z \geq y + 2$
With $a, b ,c \geq 0,$ we can rewrite this as:
$x = 1 + a$
$y = (1 + a) + (2 + b)$
$z = (1 + a) + (2 + b) + (2 + c)$
Since $z \leq 26,$ we have $0 \leq a + b + c \leq 21.$ Using stars and bars, the number of $(a, b, c)$ is $\dbinom{21 + 3 -1}{3 - 1} = 253.$

EDIT: Thanks @lulu for catching a fatal mistake! The sum could take on any value from $0$ to $21$, and in my original solution, I only accounted for one case. I will fix it as follows:
Method 1:
Answer = $\sum_{N=0}^{21} \dbinom{N + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = 2024$
Method 2 (suggested by @lulu): considering an extra variable $d$ such that $a + b + c + d = 21$
Answer = $\dbinom{21 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = 2024$

Please let me know if my answer is correct and optimal. Thank you very much!

Not sure I follow your application of Stars and Bars.  Yes, you have three non-negative integers, but they need not sum to $21$.  As you remark, they might sum to $0$, or to anything else in between $0$ and $21$.  Usual approach to that situation is to introduce a fourth non-negative integer variable $d$ and now count the number of solutions to $a+b+c+d=21$.  Clearly that also counts the triples you want.

@lulu Ahh that's a stupid mistake! I think I could sigma sum all the cases of the sum from 0 to 21. Will fix it! Thank you!

You can, but the trick of adding an extra variable is faster.  I suggest, do it both ways to confirm the methods and the result.

Another approach is to consider the four gaps made by your selection.  we have $g_1+g_2+g_3+g_4=26-3=23$.  Now $g_2, g_3$ must be at least $1$ so, letting $G_2=g_2-1$, $G_3=g_3-1$ we have $g_1+G_2+G_3+g_4=21$ as before.

@lulu I just updated the post to reflect your suggestions. Thank you very much! However, I'm struggling to understand your last approach. Could you please elaborate a bit further?

The four choices, $x,y,z$, are specified by the unchosen numbers.  Let $g_1$ denote the number of elements $<x$.  Hence, if $x=5$, $g_1=4$.  Then let $g_2=y-x$ and so on.  there are $23$ unchosen cards so $g_1+g_2+g_3+g_4=23$.  But you have a constraint:  $g_2,g_3$ must be $≥1$.  Thus we introduce $G_2,G_3$ by subtracting one from each of $g_2,g_3$.  Then the quadruple $(g_1, G_2, G_3, g_4)$ consists for four non-negative integers which sum to $21$.  Of course that's the same Stars and Bars problem we found before, using your approach plus the extra variable.  Just another route to see it.

@lulu Ahh I see! Thank you very much!

It's not really different from your idea plus the extra variable (the final gap), but I think it feels more natural.

simple brute force counting gives 2024, as you computed.
